# Check Fields' Group is blank or Not using array

Tags: php, arrays

For Example, I am having 5 variables (field values),

```
$companyname
$firstname,
$lastname,
$address1,
$address2
```

so, as per requirement, there are 2 groups over here.

```
$group1 = array('firstname','lastname','address1');
$group2 = array('companyname','address2');
```

Either Group1 Variables are required or Group2 Variables are Required.
i.e.

```
Either $firstname AND $lastname AND $address1 Can Not Be Blank 
OR
$companyname AND $address2 Can Not Be Blank.
```

**Goal is :**

this function :
$alt_req_arrays($arr1,$arr2);
should return true or false.

**Question is :**
I Want to Write this Function with minimum Code (using array functions or something like that ...)

Comment: I have tried a lots of things, hand gone success too,
but code became so much lengthy.

So, Want to optimize the code.
i have already tried to use 
array_filter , array_intersect, array_diff kind of functions but didn't reached to my expectation without getting minified version of Code.

Comment: You could post the lengthy, but working version. Some people here (like me) would understand the requirements better by looking at the code than looking at your sentences :).

Answer (score 0):

If you form your $group's  like:

```
$group1 = array('firstname' => 'dfgdf','lastname' => 'dsfsad','address1' => 'ccc');
$group2 = array('companyname' => 'a','address2' => 'fdgdf');
```

I.e. hash "field" => "value of the field", then you can use the following:

```
$group1 = array('firstname' => 'dfgdf','lastname' => 'dsfsad','address1' => 'ccc');
$group2 = array('companyname' => 'a','address2' => 'fdgdf');

function alt_req_arrays($arr1,$arr2)
{
    return !array_search(null,$arr1) || !array_search(null,$arr2);
}
var_dump(alt_req_arrays($group1,$group2));
```